# React Native TextInput multiline numeric keyboardType?

Tags: javascript, android, user-interface, react-native

I really need my TextInput to be numeric, so I have

```
<TextInput keyboardType = 'numeric' />
```

But I also am expecting a lot of digits, so I wanted to enable multiline input

```
<TextInput
    multiline = {true}
    keyboardType = 'numeric'
/>
```

But multiline doesn't appear to have any effect when it's numeric. If I make the keyboardType not numeric, then I can get multiline working.

**Is there a way to have both?**

I'm on Andoird, don't know if that makes a difference

Comment: As far as I can see, in their test modules, they are actually testing for your case. Could you give us more info, it seems like it should work.

Comment: @H.TugkanKibar When I just have `multiline`, it works the way I want: text flows to a new line when it reaches the right side of the screen. But when I make the keyboard numeric `multiline` seems to be disabled because when I type a bunch of numbers, I get to the right of the screen & then it starts scrolling horizontally (i.e. the 1st digits I entered on the left are no longer visible).
Can you provide a link to these **test modules** you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not optimal, but you can try to use this library here:

[react-native-autogrow-textinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autogrow-textinput)

Idk, if it will solve your problem, but it's a good test if you haven't tried it yet.

I hope it helps!